# Rust and Glsl identical functions throw different results

Tags: rust, floating-point, glsl

I'm making a multiplayer game with procedurally generated terrain.

On the client side, the terrain is generated with shaders, then the height map is stored and used to offset a mesh.

On the server, we only have the function that have been used to create the terrain, so we can get the terrain height only where the players are to compute collisions, without having to generate all the terrain.

Now, I have a hash function for perlin noise. This function gives me different results when used in rust and in glsl ?

Here is the glsl part :

```c
vec2 hash(vec2 v) {
    return vec2
    (
        2 * fract(sin(dot(v, vec2(763., 827.))+26.)*9283.) - 1.,
        2 * fract(sin(dot(v, vec2(135., 236.))+145.)*422.) - 1
    );
}
```

and rust :

```rust
fn dot(v1: Vector2<f32>, v2: Vector2<f32>) -> f32 {
    v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y
}

fn hash(value: Vector2<f32>) -> Vector2<f32> {
    return Vector2::new(
        2. * ((dot(value, Vector2::new(763., 827.))+26.).sin()*9283.).fract() - 1.,
        2. * ((dot(value, Vector2::new(135., 236.))+145.).sin()*422.).fract() - 1.
    );
}
```

The result are sometimes similar, for example with vec2(1., 1.), but sometimes they do show different results, like for vec2(3., 2.).

I've read that the float type of glsl and the f32 types both follow the IEEE-754 float convention, so where would the differences come from ? Do I have a way to fix this, or do I have to find a work around ?

Comment: Not too familiar with glsl but does the fact that you're using integer literals (`2`, `2` and `- 1`) in the glsl version have anything to do with it?

Comment: Higher level functions like `sin` are not required by the IEEE754 standard, which means you can have slightly different implementations on different systems. The `dot(v,{763,827})+26` part might also already have slightly different results, if one version is allowed to use FMA or to change the order of operations.